# PANDAS: When Writing To Excel Change to 1904 Date System

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Hopefully this is a super easy question, but while writing to a book, it would simplify my work if I could have it set to a 1904 date upon creation. I am currently doing it with a Macro but is creating the issue of adding 4 years to all my date fields when I do it in that order.

Is it possible while setting up excel writer to have it auto create the book set to 1904?

Thank you!

Andy

Comment: How is this related to pandas?

Comment: @TroyD Pandas.ExcelWriter, attempting to see if there is a setting within the ExcelWriter that performs this function.

Comment: workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(filename, {'date_1904': True})  You can do it with xlsxwriter, but I don't think there's a direct way from pandas.   http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html

Comment: @TroyD Ahhhh, that was a rookie mistake of mine with a hyper focus of forcing myself to do it with Pandas. I think I know how to utilize this method instead.  Thank you!

Comment: @TroyD answers shouldn't go in comments, please add yours as an answer so that others will know this issue has been solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Troy points out it can be done from XlsxWriter via the constructor. It is also possible to pass this parameter to the xlsxwriter engine in Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

df = pd.DataFrame({'Dates': [date(2018, 1, 1),
                             date(2018, 1, 2),
                             date(2018, 1, 3),
                             date(2018, 1, 4),
                             date(2018, 1, 5)],
                   })

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("pandas_example.xlsx",
                        engine='xlsxwriter',
                        options={'date_1904': True})

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

Option in the output file:

[image]

See the [Passing XlsxWriter constructor options to Pandas](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#passing-xlsxwriter-constructor-options-to-pandas) section of the XlsxWriter docs.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with xlsxwriter, but I don't think there's a direct way from pandas.

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(filename, {'date_1904': True})
```

xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html